# DBATools - pass through flat file configs to Agent Job Commands

Tags: sql-server-agent, powershell, dbatools

I'm experimenting with source controlling my SQL Agent Jobs & Schedules as `.json` files and deploying them with [the dbatools SQL Agent command suite](https://dbatools.io/command-search/?search=DbaAgent).

Given `$sa = Get-Credential` and `foo.config` of the below form...

```
{
    "Schedule":                  "Foo",
    "Disabled":                  false,
    "FrequencyType":             "Weekly",
    "FrequencyInterval":         "EveryDay",
    "FrequencySubdayType":       "Time",
    "FrequencySubdayInterval":   0,
    "FrequencyRelativeInterval": "Unused",
    "FrequencyRecurrenceFactor": 1,
    "StartDate":                 "20180823",
    "EndDate":                   "20181023",
    "StartTime":                 "070000",
    "EndTime":                   "235959"
}
```

Attempting to use `foo.config` in a solution [fails basic parsing with the following message](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/6cef68c5a43e15690f552c14f93c8852997d21c2/functions/New-DbaAgentSchedule.ps1#L156):

```
~> $foo = Get-Content foo.config | ConvertFrom-Json
~> New-DbaAgentSchedule @foo -ServerInstance "." -SqlCredential $sa
```

> WARNING: [15:50:04][New-DbaAgentSchedule] A schedule was not provided! Please provide a schedule name.

Well that sucks... Especially since the following works just fine...

```
$bar = @{
    Schedule=                  "Foo"
    Disabled=                  $false
    FrequencyType=             "Weekly"
    FrequencyInterval=         "EveryDay"
    FrequencySubdayType=       "Time"
    FrequencySubdayInterval=   0
    FrequencyRelativeInterval= "Unused"
    FrequencyRecurrenceFactor= 1
    StartDate=                 "20180823"
    EndDate=                   "20181023"
    StartTime=                 "070000"
    EndTime=                   "235959"
}

New-DbaAgentSchedule @bar -ServerInstance "." -SqlCredential $sa
```

I really don't want to bother typing out each individual `... -Param1 $foo.Param1 -Param2 $foo.Param2 ...` *because I'm lazy*. I would really much rather [splat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) my config files into the various commands. [Why won't this work!!?!1!](https://media1.tenor.com/images/ad325bd3d9ee1be4df661927772f5482/tenor.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can do is there is an option when you convert from json to actually convert it into a hastable for you...so it can save a few lines of code.

```
(Get-Content C:\temp\foo.config | ConvertFrom-Json).GetType()
<#
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
#>
(Get-Content C:\temp\foo.config | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable).GetType()
<#
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object
#>
```

I don't have any server accessible to confirm, but the output of the second command though shows it is the name/value format:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
EndTime                        235959
StartDate                      20180823
FrequencySubdayInterval        0
FrequencyType                  Weekly
Schedule                       Foo
Disabled                       False
FrequencyRelativeInterval      Unused
EndDate                        20181023
FrequencySubdayType            Time
FrequencyInterval              EveryDay
StartTime                      070000
FrequencyRecurrenceFactor      1
```

Being that the above can only work on PowerShell Core 6.1 (generally available now) you will need to use the [WindowsCompatibility](https://github.com/PowerShell/WindowsCompatibility) module to utilize dbatools within PS Core. You can do that using the following code within PS Core:

```
Install-Module WindowsCompatibility
Import-WinModule dbatools
```

The second command utilizes WinRm in order to support implicit remoting. The above would mean you have installed PowerShell Core on a Windows Machine. The documentation shows how to do this for a remote machine if required.

From there you can run the dbatools commands as you want:

[image]

Comment: Awesome feature ! Now I just have to choose between [using Powershell 6 for access to the `-AsHashTable` flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6#optional-parameters) or Powershell 5 for access to dbatools 

Comment: You can use dbatools in PowerShell 6.1 via `WindowsCompatibilty` module. I'll update the answer with steps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, 4 hours ago self... if you had bothered to inspect the types of `$foo` and `$bar`, you might not have wasted a whole afternoon swearing loudly in your open office floor plan as you scroll fruitlessly through the documentation...

```
~> ($foo | Get-Member).TypeName[0]
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

~> ($bar | Get-Member).TypeName[0]
System.Collections.Hashtable
```

There's even [a convenient, generalized solution on this very Q&A Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740128/pscustomobject-to-hashtable) for converting a `PSCustomObject` into a `HashTable`.

```
$foo.psobject.properties | foreach -begin {
    $foo=@{}
} -process {
    $foo."$($_.Name)" = $_.Value
} -end {$foo}

~> New-DbaAgentSchedule @foo -ServerInstance "." -SqlCredential $sa
```

Easy peasy, lemon squeezy.

So splat away, ya big crazy. And when you're done feeling stupid, maybe share the workaround online in case it helps someone else. And if you're feeling super proactive, maybe consider setting aside some time to [contribute to the module](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/development/contributing.md).